# Curious why my main method won't print my Array

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

I'm working on an algorithm analysis assignment and I'm running into some issues implementing the main method.  The idea was to create new arrays in the main method (at the bottom), and then apply the algorithms to see how they affect the numbers in the Array.  The `fillArray()` method is declared after instantiating my new arrays, telling it to fill `mainArray` with random integers which is then copied to the `nextArray` using `copyArray()`.  After this I (want to) print the arrays using a `toString`.  I don't know where exactly I'm going wrong but for some reason I'm getting nothing back when I run the program when I'm expecting to see two identical arrays printing.

The program compiles just fine though, the main method just doesn't seem to be working. I've also included both the `fillArray` and `copyArray` methods just in case that's where the error is although I'm not seeing it.

Here is my code:

```
public class AnalysisAssignmentMod 
{

// fill the contents of the array passed as parameter at random
public static void fillArray(int array[])
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }    

}        

// returns a new array with a copy of each of the values from the array passed as parameter
public static int[] copyArray(int[] array)
{
    int array1[] = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = array[i];
    }    
    return array1;
}      

public static void main(String[] args){
  int[] mainArray = new int[10];
  int[] nextArray = new int[10];
  fillArray(mainArray);
  nextArray = copyArray(mainArray);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainArray));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextArray));
}

}
```

Comment: Seems to me they work as expected: http://ideone.com/x0h6ct

Comment: Your code works fine in netbeans this is the output i get : [2129662845, 817272636, 219817982, 272537868, 2094738368, 434779771, 748896846, 810069389, 578046546, 547723730]
[2129662845, 817272636, 219817982, 272537868, 2094738368, 434779771, 748896846, 810069389, 578046546, 547723730]

Comment: *the main method just doesn't seem to be working.* Okay but how did you come to know that it's not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse, I created a new project, added your class, included the import java.util.*; you left out of your sample code then ran the code.  The Console windows shows the following output:

[755337529, 1336068446, 1777237203, 780687210, 536376228, 310689627, 1554567944, 2039849273, 128854867, 1662084709]
[755337529, 1336068446, 1777237203, 780687210, 536376228, 310689627, 1554567944, 2039849273, 128854867, 1662084709]

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing as well, running it in Eclipse (I was originally executing it in jgrasp and getting wonky results).  Now I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting arrays of 10 elements with 10 integers in each element when I just want 1-2 integers in each element.

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the use of MAX_VALUE in the random integer generator.  Thank you very much for trying to help!  I'm still learning java and I'm starting to find I need to find a single IDE to consistently work with.  My professors have been changing them up on me the past couple semesters.  I'm thinking Eclipse is a good choice, although I've heard good things about NetBeans too.  Maybe that will help prevent dumb errors like this in the future.  Really sorry for wasting yours and everyone else's time.  Cheers

Comment: @TimTolbert I recommend IntelliJ if you're looking for a good IDE. It's very easy and enjoyable to work in!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you import java.util.Arrays; and it should work.

[image: Here is the output from eclipse]